# How to get the data from SAP service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

A SAP service has a method called GetDataFromTable which takes the parameter of string arrays for where clause and columns to be exposed. I have a snapshot of the SAP table which shows just the name of the table and the fields. From that snapshot I have to get the data. My code is as shown :

```
string[] colForTable = new string[13];

colForTable [0] = "ABCD";
colForTable [1] = "EFGH";
colForTable [2] = "IJKL";
colForTable [3] = "MNOP";
colForTable [4] = "QRST";
colForTable [5] = "UVWX";
colForTable [6] = "YZCF";
colForTable [7] = "IOPH";
colForTable [8] = "TRSG";
colForTable [9] = "BKRAKT";
colForTable [10] = "TYDG";
colForTable [11] = "UYTE";
colForTable [12] = "IOPL";

string[] whereForTable = new string[1];

whereForTable [0] = "ABCD NE '0'";

DataSet T093CDataset = myService.GetDataFromTable(token, ref errorFlag, ref errorMsg, "TableName", colForTable, whereForTable , 1);
```

This method is working for few of the tables but not for this one. Is there any other way of writing a `WHERE` clause which can get me the data. Most of the fields are of type varchar or whatever it is in SAP.

Comment: Add the table fields and their types too.

Comment: If the 10th field is `BKRAKT` and your DataSet is named `T093CDataset`, you're most likely talking about table `T093C`. Obfuscating everything that is relevant to understand the problem does not help. Please add more information about the service you use and especially the error messages. "It ain't working" isn't helpful either.

Comment: The problem is that even I don't have much information. I had to change the data due to security concerns. We communicate with SAP team and they provide only the snapshots which do not even have the data types of the fields. Yes table name is T093C. May be we'll have to have one more discussion with them regarding the data fetching.